# why websocket connection creation does not pass through http?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, tcp, websocket

i tumbled across websocket and http.

I have written below example:

```
var fs   = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log ("HTTP Request created...");
  // I am responding something here..
});

server.listen(1234, function() {
   console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 1234');
});


var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
            httpServer: server
});

wsServer.on('request', function(re){
        var conn = re.accept(null, re.origin);
            console.log ("Accepted New Connection..");
            conn.on('message', function(message) {
                console.log ('message received' + message.utf8Data);
            });
           });
```

I tried in two ways connecting to this server.

```
1) Through Browser.
2) through node.js application
```

When I tried reaching this server through browser ex: http:IP:1234,
I get "HTTP Request received.." gets printed, where as when I try with 
below code in Node.js, I do not see this message getting printed.

```
var WebSocket = require('ws')
  ws = new WebSocket('ws://IP:1234');

    ws.on('open', function() {
            console.log ("WebSocket opened..");
            ws.send('something');
    });
ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message.data);
});
```

When I tried to connect to webserver through
    ws = new WebSocket('ws://IP:1234');

why is It not getting through HTTP?. My basic understanding is **Websocket is just an upgrade on top of HTTP**, in that case, I would assume WebSocket(), in turn connectes through HTTP to the server right?. Or Am i confused?.

Answer (score 0):

Websocket requests don't trigger a [`request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request) event on the HTTP server instance (for which the function you pass to `createServer` is a listener).

If you want to watch websocket requests on the HTTP server, listen to [`upgrade`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_upgrade_1) events:

```
server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) { ... });
```

I assume it's because `http` will handle the handshake/upgrade itself that this is done through a different event.